# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS In Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

This is my controller code (Home.php)
`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        if (session('id')) {
            return redirect()->to(site_url('/profil'));
        }
        return view('signin/signin');
    }
}
```

`

and this is my Filters.php config
`

```
<?php

namespace Config;


class Filters extends BaseConfig
{
   
    public $aliases = [
        'csrf'          => CSRF::class,
        'toolbar'       => DebugToolbar::class,
        'honeypot'      => Honeypot::class,
        'invalidchars'  => InvalidChars::class,
        'secureheaders' => SecureHeaders::class,
        'loginfilter'    => LoginFilter::class,
    ];

    public $globals = [
        'before' => [
            // 'honeypot',
            'csrf',
            // 'invalidchars',
        ],
        'after' => [
            'toolbar',
            // 'honeypot',
            // 'secureheaders',
        ],
    ];
}
```

`

loginfilter.php
`

```
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use CodeIgniter\Filters\FilterInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

class loginfilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        if (!session('id')) {
            return redirect()->to('/');
        }
    }

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

`

Hi,
Im trying to use filter to all of my controller except login controller
but its doesn't seems to work,
above code is my controller and filters config

and this is the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIrzB.png)

Comment: Are you sure your config/Filters.php has just that?

Comment: no it;s not. i only not write it. but the rest code is default from CI and i didn't change any of it.

Comment: Please add the rules you added in the Filter.php because that's probably what is caused the infinite redirect.

Comment: no worries, it's solved now. the redirect to base_url() make the infinite redirect. thank you for tryin to help

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).